# Records inserted into the tables gets deleted if SQL command line console is closed abruptly without disconnecting from DB user

Tags: sql, database, command-line, oracle11g, console

Records inserted into the tables gets deleted if SQL command line console is closed abruptly without disconnecting from DB user.

Also , if console is closed after disconnecting from the Db using 'disconnect', records are being retained and shown in next login to DB

Is this fine or its because of any fault in my machine?

Comment: I think, `commit` is for dropping the tables but not for inserting records.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't explicitly committing your transaction, but there's a setting in whichever tool/code you're using to connect to the database that is set to auto commit on exit. If you want your records to be permanently inserted, you should run a commit afterwards. Note that a commit works on the entire transaction, so if you have run several sets of insert statements within the same transaction, they will all be committed.

Comment: It is absolutely fine, because as Boneist explained, the default in most front-ends is to COMMIT your uncommitted changes upon exit (unless you give an explicit ROLLBACK before exiting). This depends on your front-end application and is a setting that can be changed in most cases. Other front-ends will ASK before exiting - whether you want to COMMIT or ROLLBACK pending transactions. As for "dirty" exit (without properly disconnecting from the session), the rows are "lost" the same way you lose your work if you didn't save it and there is a power outage. Same idea.

Comment: Thanks Guys. you answers gave an idea of what is happening. Thanks again.